# XML Feed... where am I going wrong?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have had very few problems working with feeds and PHP lately, but this has got me stumped...

XML looks like this...

```
<Order>
    <Booking id="272591086"/>
</Order>
```

My PHP looks like below, but does not display the booking id from the above XML, where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
$theurl = 'http://www.website.co.uk/dev/test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($theurl);
$result = $xml->xpath("/Order/Booking");
foreach ($result as $ref) 
{
   echo 'Booking Ref '. $ref['id'] .'';
}
?>
```

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.org/6wQheCQD, so the logical explanation would be that the URL you are loading is not giving the XML you are showing.

Comment: By putting your XML code into a "test.xml" and adding `$theurl = "test.xml"`, it's working for me as well

Answer (score 0):

I second @Gordon's comment, but in case the XML is in fact the one you're showing try this little adjustment in your XPATH query:

```
$result = $xml->xpath("//Booking");
```

#### [Working example](http://codepad.org/KBbWcJN1)